# Is there a way to store functions in a collection and access them with a key

Tags: rust

Im trying to use a dictionary to call functions. Unfortunately 1) tuples cannot be looped over 2) if I place the function in a wrapper then and implement unwrap I must use a type 3) I cant create traits for enum variants. The types the functions produce are not limited to basic types. So using a `Box<T>` and converting it to a string isnt an option... is there anything Im missing?

```
enum Wrapper {
    Wrapper(Function<T>)
}

trait Unwrap<T> {
    fn unwrap(self) -> T;
}

struct Function<T>(fn() -> T);

impl<T> Unwrap<T> for Function<T> {
    fn unwrap(self) -> T {
        match self {
            Function(function) => function(),
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
  let test_vec = vec![
      Wrapper(Function(||-> u64{1})), 
      Wrapper(Function(||-> String{
          let str = String::from("Hello"); 
          println!(str); 
          str}))
  ];

  let test_hashmap: HashMap<String, Wrapper> = (
      ("One", Wrapper(Function(||-> u64{21341}))),
      ("Two",Wrapper(Function(||-> u64{0})))
  );
}
```

Pseudo code:

FIle: {Hello, my name is X, I am hungry, I like to eat}.

Collection : [(hungry, fn()->X), (eat, ffn()->X),(jump, ffn()->X),(wait, fn()->X)]

File Parser: {if file contains keys, push associated functions to new collection}

fn unpack(new collection){ fn hungery() -> X; fn eat() -> X }

Comment: It is... not obvious from your question what you are actually after. What does iteration over tuples have with the rest of the question? Rust's collections like `Vec` and `HashMap` are homogeneous - all keys and values must be of the same type. Polymorphic behavior is achieved with `Box<dyn Trait>` or `&dyn Trait`. If your functions must return different `T`, then you need to encapsulate the `T` in a trait, and have them return that. Perhaps [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=668128e02a9f3af64e4df948d77df3ac) is what you're after?

Comment: @user4815162342 Assume I'm returning a string, then creating a connection to a database, then printing some text,etc and these functions are accessed using a dictionary (list of words)... So all the functions have different return types.

Comment: Take a look at the code - the functions **do** have a different return type - one returns `u64`, another a `String`. The return type is constrained to implement a trait of your choosing (and since it's your trait you can implement it on ordinary types like `u64` and `String`), which the code that owns the dictionary can access. (In this code it's the `Quack` trait, which the dictionary uses to call `quack()`.)

Comment: @user4815162342 I cound not get it compile so that I can tinker with it to understand what youre after...

Comment: Wrong link, sorry about that. This one compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b708ffcc5cfdcf1b4695670500f646f5

Comment: @user4815162342 Assuming the data structures for say a MySql Connection... how would I return that using your code? I dont just need to print values but return more complex types...

Comment: I think there's a lot of confusion here because, as already mentioned, the types of elements in a `HashMap` must all be the same, but to reconcile what you should do about it, it depends on *what you want to do* with the values returned by the functions in the map.

Comment: @kmdreko Ill give you example of my intentions. I want to parse a file that contains words found in a dictionary. Something like "Given a database, When a connection is connection established, Then change user_2 user_name to "John"" (given, when, then, database, connection, established) are in the dictionary. From that it will dynamically create a context (a functions set context) to accomplish the task or test a set of conditions...

Comment: @kmdreko Im trying to create scope dynamically...

Comment: The `quack()` function would connect to MySQL or whatever. You don't need to return anything other than `Box<dyn Quack>`.

Comment: @user4815162342 `let test =  conn.query("SELECT restart FROM RESTART").unwrap()[0];
   |                     ^^^^^ method not found in` `Box<dyn Quack>` Im not sure how that would work

Comment: @user4815162342 Im under the current understanding that trait objects "erase" the inner type

Comment: You'd place that code inside the implementation of `quack()`. That's where the type is not erased, and that's the whole point of the `Quack` trait. (Imagine it being called `DoMyActualWork`.) Hope this helps.

Comment: @user4815162342 I want to create a context in main not quack... I'm guessing theres no way to do this...

Comment: If `quack()` is called from main, what do you care where the context is created? Can you add to the question the exact code you'd like to be able to write in `main()`? Currently we have very little to go by, and your question is basically unanswerable.

Comment: @user4815162342 Where the context is created does not matter, it needs to be dynamic. I need to dynamically create a function set and unpack it. 

EX: 

FIle: {Hello, my name is X, I am hungry, I like to eat}.

Collection : [(hungry, fn()->X), (eat, ffn()->X),(jump, ffn()->X),(wait, fn()->X)]

File Parser: {if files contains keys, push functions to new collection}

fn unpack(new collection){
fn hungery() -> X;
fn eat()
-> X
}

Comment: @user4815162342 I added pseudo code above for readability

Comment: That pseudocode doesn't show the kind of code that you'd like to write in `main()`, that opens database connections and whatnot. Sorry, I give up.

Comment: Here is one last-ditch attempt: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=79b9d4e516987044a3a97179625cfad1

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want? I fixed the code up a bit.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Unwrap<T> {
    fn unwrap(&self) -> T;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Function<T>(fn() -> T);

impl<T> Unwrap<T> for Function<T> {
    fn unwrap(&self) -> T {
        self.0()
    }
}

fn main() {
  let test_hashmap = HashMap::from([
      ("One", Function(||-> u64{21341})),
      ("Two", Function(||-> u64{0}))
  ]);
  println!("{:?}", test_hashmap.get("One").unwrap().unwrap());

  // prints 21341
}
```

Comment: I need it to return different types. Say a connection to a database, or a JSON string, or a u64... etc

Comment: Ah, then you can `Box<dyn>` it or construct an `enum` with the choices

Comment: How would you go about doing so? Im a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rust's trait objects instead of trying to create a wrapper class for your objects. Use a `Box` (heap-allocated data) to store your `dyn Fn()` and you can store it in a HashMap like this (notice the extra pair of `()` when the closure needs to be evaluated):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum ReturnType {
    Int(i32),
    Str(String),
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, Box<dyn Fn() -> ReturnType + 'static>> =
        HashMap::new();

    map.insert("one", Box::new(|| { ReturnType::Int(1) }));
    map.insert("two", Box::new(|| { ReturnType::Int(2) }));
    map.insert("red", Box::new(|| { ReturnType::Str("red".to_string()) }));
    map.insert("blue", Box::new(|| { ReturnType::Str("blue".to_string()) }));
    
    let strings = vec!["two", "blue"];
    
    for item in strings {
        let fish = map.get(item).unwrap()();
        
        match fish {
            ReturnType::Int(x) => {
                println!("I caught {} fish today.", x);
            }
            ReturnType::Str(s) => {
                println!("I caught a fish which was colored {}", s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: saw the comments between you and @BallpointBen and added his enum idea to give you the ability to return different types from your closures

Comment: How d o I unwrap the enum variant and access the value?

Comment: Ideally, you would use a `match` statement to provide a case for every possible variant, but you can also use an `if let` to de-structure into a variable. For example:
`if let ReturnType::Int(x) = map.get("One").unwrap()() { println!("I just read {}" x) }` would print "I just read 1".

Comment: If you want to provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish, I could probably help come up with a better explanation

Comment: I have a list of strings. I want to use those strings to match to a key in a hashmap of use a match statement to match the string to an index, I dont really care. Once I access the index/key the function stored in the vec or hashmap is called.

Comment: I edited my answer with another example. For each string in the `strings` vec, it will use it as the key to the HashMap, and evaluate the closure which will be stored in `fish`. The `match` statement will pull the item out of the enum, and use it in a `println` statement. The match arms can be combined like `ReturnType::Int(v) | ReturnType::Str(v) => {}` if both of them do the same thing.

Comment: I need to return the value not just print it

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the value, printing it is just my example of being able to use it. Just change the program around a bit and it will work in the way you need it to.

Comment: Thank you for working with me! Im not sure I understand.. match arms cannot return unlike types.

Comment: @stack_me You shouldn't try to return unlike types from the `match`, that's what the `ReturnType` enum is for. Instead you should do what you need to do with the returned type *within the match arm*.

Comment: @kmdreko The dictionary will be 100s, maybe 1000s of words long. Each word will have an associated function. I would be fine with creating a macro that generates an enum / match arm set but then how will it know what functions to associate with the match arm?